# Character Controller not colliding in Unity

Tags: unity

I have a character controller on my player object however it will not collide with the terrain and will just fall through, what am i doing wrong. (PS I am really new to unity)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Unity but I suppose folks will want to know how you've set up your character. Collider? What is it set to collide with? Etc.

Comment: We generally need what's called a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. That is, you should walk us through every step we'd need to follow to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project. Try **editing your question** to include this detail.

Answer (score 2):

To make collision between a Character Controller and scenery work in Unity, you have to ensure that both objects have a collider component. (BoxCollider, SphereCollider, CapsuleCollider or MeshCollider) Check your Character Controller properties as well to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your character and terrain have a collider component(You can check this in inspector), and make sure that you're don't using for example: BoxCollider2D in 3d space.